# How can I set Focal Point coordinates in a View or Twig?

Tags: views, 8, theming, media

I use the Focal Point module in D8, and I'm trying to figure out how I can access the X and Y coordinates of the focal point through Twig in either a view or Twig template so I can use them as background-position coordinates.

I can't seem to find any documentation... could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support request to a third-party module hosted on drupal.org and this must be posted to this module's issue queue.

Comment: for reference ... this is the issue on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/project/focal_point/issues/3112099